# Trying to get a variable out of Sax JS

Tags: node.js, saxparser

I'm using [SAX JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax) to parse an XML file in Node. I want it to produce an object of the parsed file, but the best I seem to be able to do is `console.log` my parsed data.

I'm really new to streams in Node. I've googled and tried some things, but my fundamental problems seems to be that I can't get a grasp on where to begin with streams and how they relate to SAX JS.

How do I output the parsed XML file from SAX to a JS object?

## Addendum

Ideally I'd like a JS object in a variable, but I'd also be happy getting JSON text out, which I could deserialize into a variable.

With SAX JS, I tried `this.write(JSON.stringify(val));` from the `closetag` event handler and it produces countless `error! Error: Invalid characters in closing tag`. I really have no idea what I'm doing here.

I've already tried xml2js (didn't do what I need), and xml4js (not maintained). The big problem I had with xml2js is that [my xml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenGreekAndLatin/First1KGreek/master/data/tlg0086/tlg031/tlg0086.tlg031.1st1K-grc1.xml)'s text includes essential data in self-closing tags that ended up in a different key, completely separate from the text.

Here's an XML structure somewhat like what I need it to handle:

```
<p>The quick brown fox <del>jumps</del> 
over the <lb n="15"/> lazy dog.</p>
```

I need all the text, and I need some what to insert the attribute of the `lb` tag into the text with a custom format.

## Addendum 2

Here's a better example, along with an ideal result:

```
<p>The quick brown fox <del>jumps</del> 
over the <lb n="15"/> lazy 
<note type="marginal">325a</note> dog.</p>
```

Result:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the [line 15] lazy [B:325a] dog.
```

Answer (score 2):

From the sax npm [package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sax#what-this-is-probably-not) we can see:

> You can use it to build an object model out of XML, but it doesn't do
>   that out of the box.

Perhaps, you might want to rethink your choice and take a look at one of the available alternatives unless you really need streams if XML file is huge and doesn't fit into machine memory.

As an example, here is how we can construct on object representation of an xml file using [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser):

```
const parser = require('fast-xml-parser');
const data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend! <pb n="1"/>  And have a plenty of sleep!</body>
</note>`;
const xmlObj = parser.parse(data, {
    ignoreAttributes: false,
    allowBooleanAttributes: true,
    parseNodeValue: true,
    parseAttributeValue: true
});
console.log('XML object: ', JSON.stringify(xmlObj));
```

The output will be:

```
XML object:  {"note":{"to":"Tove","from":"Jani","heading":"Reminder","body":{"#text":"Don't forget me this weekend2!And have a plenty of sleep!","pb":{"@_n":1}}}}
```

I've prepared a [working demo on Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/EasyPlayfulShelfware).

If a file is big enough but fits into memory, you might want to spin a child process to offload the main thread.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. I've already tried xml2js (didn't do what I need), and xml4js (not maintained). The big problem I had with xml2js is that [my xml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenGreekAndLatin/First1KGreek/master/data/tlg0086/tlg031/tlg0086.tlg031.1st1K-grc1.xml)'s text includes essential data in self-closing tags that ended up in a different key, completely separate from the text.

Comment: Just cloned your runkit and tried adding a self-closing tag in the middle of one of the text nodes. Unfortunately fast-xml-parser drops all of the text after the child tag—definitely not the behavior I need.

Comment: @JohnK, RunKit uses 3.2.0, however, 3.12.7 doesn't seem to have the issue you've mentioned in a sense that it doesn't omit everything that goes after the child tag in a node's text. I've also updated my answer above. Please, check one once more when you have time.

Comment: If you need to keep these self-closing tags as part of the text, then one of the possible solutions would be utilizing custom `tagValueProcessor` function that will make sure a self-closing tag will stay in a text and not going to be pulled off.

Comment: Viacheslav, thanks, that is somewhat better. As your second comment acknowledges, I need the tag attribute value in the text. I wish there were some documentation that described how to use `tagValueProcessor` (and the other value processor), or at least an example. The documentation is pretty sparse.

Comment: The I guess `fast-xml-parser` might be the wrong way to go since even traversal object that gets back after the call to `getTraversalObj` contains value of `val: 'The quick brown foxover thelazydog.',`, which means from that point it's not really feasible to determine where the child tag was initially placed. I propose you to search for some npm package that generates an AST representation of XML and then traverse it the way you need to get the desired formatting.